# jQuery datepicker with php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i use jQuery datepicker. i disabled input text and wanted use it as simple calendar

> http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline

but now i need to make it with php and mysql, so as retrieve news from database on selected date. for instance when admin adds news on 2011-07-07 i want to link this day on calendar. sorry for my bad english but if u understood please help, i really found lots of documentations but couldn't did.

i used

> onselect
>   also
>   beforeShowDay

but cannot understand. is there any chance to make it like news calendar?

help me with a small code please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`setDate`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate).

```
$('...').datepicker('setDate', date object);
```

Comment: I made code

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { window.open("?action=news_archive&date=" + dateText + "&lang=<?=$lang?>"); }
    }
   );
  });

Answer (score 0):

you can use the before show function of the date field to call a location.

`$('input.dateSelect').datepicker();`

then have a button that follows the input

`<a href="javascript:;" title="get the new from this date!" onclick="[[call to js function]]">[ get news ]</a>`

javascript function

`...
window.location.href = "www.foo.com/news.php?date="+$('.dateSelect').val();
...`

There is one of several ways to skin this cat, and not necessarily the best.

I hope this helps someone else with the same issues!

bo huttinger